# Rails: how to redirect to a specific page after signing out with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question about using Devise in Rails.
How can I redirect to a specific page after signing out (destroying a user session)?

I tried the following in Application Controller, which does not seem to be working:

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path 
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the specific problem you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

That should work according to the [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out).

Maybe you've missed the last line:

> You should also override method `Devise::Controllers::Helpers#stored_location_for` in your application controller, to return `nil`. This applies to `after_sign_in_path_for` also. YMMV.

Comment: And how would I "override method Devise::Controllers::Helpers#stored_location_for in your application controller, to return nil?"

Comment: I've just checked the source code, it should work with `after_sign_out_path_for`. However, make sure to add it as a `private` method.

Comment: I added it as a private method, but it's not working yet.  When I sign out as user 1, the browser stays at http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out.1 for some reason.

How can I see the source code?

Comment: The default behavior is to redirect the user to the app's root so the method doesn't seem to be called at all. Here is the source code: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L228